# Origine del termine ottuso

Tags: etymology

Che origine ha il termine figurato e dispregiativo **ottuso**?

eg.: `ma sei proprio o.!`

La mia curiosità nello specifico è se ha qualche legame con il numero 8, che sdraiato rappresenta l'infinito che a sua volta, con un po' di immaginazione, è un concetto che può essere collegato alla stupidità umana che a quanto pare (o così si dice) non ha limiti (¿).

Oppure se la sua origine è legata alla geometria che per qualche ragione ha portato a credere che gli angoli acuti (minore di un angolo retto e maggiore di 0°) dimostrino maggiore perspicacia di quelli ottusi (cioè superiore a 90° e inferiore a 180°).

Comment: Hai pensato a consultare un vocabolario, prima di porre la domanda?

Comment: no, volevo sapere la vostra

Comment: Ecco, l'idea è che uno faccia il lieve sforzo di cercare un po' per conto suo. Poi, se non trova la risposta, o ne trova di contraddittorie, o per qualche motivo non ne è persuaso, sottopone la questione qui.

Comment: l'ho fatto, [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ottuso/), [qui](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/O/ottuso.shtml) e [qui](http://www.etimo.it/?term=ottuso)

Comment: Ti è rimasto qualche dubbio o si può chiudere la domanda?

Comment: I link li avevo letti prima di porre la domanda. I dubbi sono ancora gli stessi

Comment: Nel Treccani, ad esempio, l'origine latino è chiaro. Qual è il problema? "Ottuso" è il "contrario" di "acuto" in senso geometrico e in senso figurato.

Comment: E di sicuro non ha niente a che vedere col numero otto e neanche col simbolo dell'infinito.

Comment: non ha senso. Perchè un qualcosa di acuto è più intelligente di qualcosa di ottuso? l'unico lontano legame che ci posso vedere è nella frase "che manca di penetrazione" , una lama o una freccia, con lama  ad angolo acuto, ha capacità di penetrazione.

Comment: Non c'è nessun problema, comunque è un piacere parlare con voi davero

Comment: Scusa, in italiano forse non è "acuto", ma "acutezza" quello che in senso figurato è il contrario dell'essere ottuso.

Comment: lese, deciditi: non avevi letto le definizioni dei dizionari come hai scritto nel tuo primo commento, o le avevi lette come hai scritto nel terzo? A ogni modo, se le avessi lette avresti visto che il numero otto non c'entra niente, e che sia un intelletto che un angolo ottusi sono usi figurati del significato fondamentale: smussato, poco aguzzo. [segue]

Comment: Quindi, sì, l'idea fondamentale è quella che hai colto: «che manca di penetrazione». La metafora vecchia di millenni è quella che una persona sveglia è acuta, ha aguzzato l'ingegno, ha un intelletto penetrante, un cervello fine, una mente sottile, va a fondo delle cose. Una più tarda di comprendonio, tutto il contrario e cioè appunto è come una lama che non taglia, smussata.

Comment: All'inizio temevo che ti riferissi ad un altra metafora vecchia di millenni. Vabbè dai, grazie al vostro aiuto sono riuscito ad andare al nocciolo della questione, anche se stavate cominciando a farmi sentire ottuso. Grazie!

Comment: @DaG: Forse potresti scriverlo come risposta.

Comment: @Charo: Va bene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il senso letterale di “ottuso” (dal latino *obtundĕre*) è quello di ”smussato, spuntato” detto di lame e simili.

Per il suo senso figurato, detto di un intelletto non brillante, l'idea fondamentale, come riporta per esempio il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ottuso/), è «che manca di penetrazione». La metafora vecchia di millenni è quella che una persona sveglia è acuta, ha aguzzato l'ingegno, ha un intelletto penetrante, un cervello fine, una mente sottile, va a fondo delle cose. Per una più tarda di comprendonio vale tutto il contrario, e cioè appunto è come una lama che non taglia, smussata.